# Why mToolbar and Toolbar doesn't work in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-widget, android-toolbar

I tried everything. But I can't It figure out.
Always tells me that they doesn't work--->mToolbar and Toolbar<---

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Toolbar;      

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private RecyclerView postList;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private Toolbar supportActionBar;



mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("home");
```

Also my Grandle. I don't know if it helps.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

I tried android.widget.support.v7.Toolbar; but It didn't help

The mistake was :

from --> `import android.widget.Toolbar`

To --> `import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: [Screenshot](https://prnt.sc/qrzo9y)

Comment: Could you also share the layout for the `MainActivity`?

Comment: @SotirisKapa please transcribe the error into your question, and feel free to include include the screen shot there. By doing so other members can find your specific error using search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using androidX in your xml file, but in your java file you import the old library , try to remove

```
   import android.widget.Toolbar
```

and put the suitable one that you imported before in xml

```
  import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
```

Answer (score 1):

By chance, in your layout, are you using the androidx version of the Toolbar? If you are, that's what is creating this error. In your Activity, you are referencing a different version of Toolbar.

Comment: Actually I am new on android studio. How can I change androidx or how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please post your layout and post your Activity class in its entirety. You should be able to see if inside the XML tags of the Toolbar if your are using. i.e.

```<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the error may be in the import of the Toolbar class
in your exepmlo you are already using the androidrx standard but in the Toolbar object you are using the old import

```
import android.widget.Toolbar
```

But the new import is

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
```

Comment: That's It man thanks a lot. All that time I tried to edit my post but they wanted to tell more details.